# generate network errors for testing

Tags: javascript, testing

I would like to know. Is there any option to generate random network errors for testing of js code? I am trying to implement some error handling during the upload of files to the PHP server but "unfortunately", my internet is rather stable at home + I do it in LAN. I was trying to use a VPN switch, but it switches almost instantly, without network disruption (or at least it seems that way) and even if it worked, I do not feel like using that solution because of that frustrating routine that comes with it...
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it and plugging it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chrome inspector's Network tab has options for, among other things,

- [throttling your connection](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#throttle)
- [blocking requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network#block)
- and simulating offline mode for your tab (which might do the trick if you hit it during a request).

Comment: Thanks! simulating offline and throttling will come handy in testing!